# Random Number Generator with Range - Swift 3?

Tags: swift3

Need to set a random number between say 3 and 7. Everything I find is for Swift 2 and no longer works in Swift 3.

Thanks

Comment: thanks for the link but I've tried these and no dice

Comment: What you mean no dice?. make sure you import UIKit for iOS or Cocoa for macOS

Answer (score 1):

This should work for my purposes.

var tapsNeeded = arc4random_uniform(4) + 3;